# web api 2 cors not working

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I create a web service on Web API and try to use it from angular 2 application.
I install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.3 and configure it to allow cors.
It hosted on local IIS at localhost/RestfulAPI

WebApiConfig

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi 2",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"); // origins, headers, methods
        config.EnableCors(cors);
    }
}
```

controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/product/details")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetProductsDetails([FromUri]ProductSearch model)
{
    using (var unitOfWork = Factory.Create())
    {
        var products = (from p in await unitOfWork.GetProductsAsync(model?.CategoryID, model?.BrandID, model?.ProductStateID, null, model?.PartnerID,
                    true, model?.Code)
            orderby p.Code
            select p).ToArray();
        return return Json(products);
    }
}
```

But I'm still get error in browser.

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:12012' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

How could it be, that I enabled all cors, but it still not working?

Upd.1.
I try to handle an options request like bellow

```
 public class PreflightRequestsHandler : DelegatingHandler
        {
            protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                if (request.Headers.Contains("Origin") && request.Method.Method.Equals("OPTIONS"))
                {
                    var response = new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
                    // Define and add values to variables: origins, headers, methods (can be global)               
                    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
                    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
                    var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpResponseMessage>();
                    tsc.SetResult(response);
                    return tsc.Task;
                }
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }

        }
```

But get an error: Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: Are you sure this is not on the options request?

Comment: Whats difference if it is? And how to enable it in this case?

Comment: Try moving the EnableCors to the top of method, before everything.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using Api controller instead of the plain controller which inherits from Apicontroller class.
I had same issue, then i figured out that i was using plain controller, i rectified it and i am not able to access and fetch the data from the api controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below nuget

[Nuget for CORS](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/invoking-webapi-controller-action-with-multiple-parameters-in-cors/)